# TIME SERIES plot error

Tags: forecasting

i have been working on this project since last week which involves building ARIMA model for forecast . i am able to convert the data in timeseries format however when i try to plot the timeseries data it gives following error. i have been reading the replies which is related to my question but unfortunately i am not able to turn this error around. will really appreciate if i can get some help. thank you.
following is the code.

```
data=read.csv("C:/Users/mdd/Desktop/Projects/Codes/Forecasting/data.csv",header = TRUE,sep=",",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
View(data)
head(data)
str(data)
class(data)
is.numeric(data$sales)
is.factor(data$sales)
sales[[1]]=as.Date(sales[[1]],format='%m/%d/%Y')
sales_ts=ts(data$sales,frequency = 52,start = c(2013,1))
sales_ts
View(sales_ts)
str(sales_ts)
class(sales_ts)
is.numeric(sales_ts)
is.factor(sales_ts)
start(sales_ts) #start of time series
end(sales_ts) #start of time series
frequency(sales_ts)
summary(sales_ts)
is.na(sales_ts)
```

following is the error i get

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, log, ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, NULL, log = log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```